# Visual c++ trouble with SDL ttf

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've just started to learn SDL in visual c++. I've followed the steps on lazyfoo for setting up sdl2 in visualC++. I've added SDL2_image aswell but when i add SDL2_ttf the exact same way i get a compiling error. It says: lnk1104: cannot open file 'sdl2_ttf.lib
i've added the include and lib folders and i've put SDL2_ttf.lib at linker input.
I've also added the SDL2_ttf.dll file in the debug folder.
What did i do wrong or what did I forget?
thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you actually using `SDL2_ttf` and `SDL2_image`? Because if not, I think you can figure out where your mistake is

Comment: Well, just changing the nature of the question is not really encourage here on stackoverflow, but anyway .Are you sure that your linker can find the location, to be sure just put in the full path including the file in your linker input something like "C:\path\to\gfile\SDL2_ttf.lib"; (including with the quotes)

Comment: This planet needs more people like you

Answer (score 1):

Those 2 libraries are not located inside SDL2_image library. You should install SDL2_mixer library and SDL2_ttf library as well, and link them in the visual studio like you linked the SDL2_image library.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a further comment for those who experience this problem. The following steps solved the issue for me:

- Download relevant extension library files
- put **.h header and .dll library** files wherever your project is looking for them (based on the Visual Studio settings) **AND where Windows is looking for them** (based on the system environment variable settings). If VS "Additional Dependencies" and Windows system variable settings are looking in the same folder, then you only need to add your .h and .dll files to one folder. If, like me, you like to split up your debug vs release files, then you need to make sure your .h and .dll files are visible to BOTH the Windows OS and Visual Studio.
- In Visual Studio, update Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies to include the .dll that you have just added to your file structure
- Make sure to add relevant #include in the pre-processor statements
- Make sure you're not mixing configurations or platforms! i.e. a 64-bit windows .dll won't work with a x86 .dll
- Restart Visual Studio (not required unless Windows system variable settings are actually changed)

Happy SDL coding :-D